# Issues with v4 bootstrap classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap v4, with CDN:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">`

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

**Issue**

Some of the classes aren't working, such as `pull-right` or `navbar-right`. I reverted back to using an older version of Bootstrap and the classes worked, but the layout of course changed and I would prefer to carry on using v4. I'm unable  to float two `li` elements to the right of the main group of `li` elements.

**Aim**

To find out why classes aren't working in v4, and to float the two `li` items,  `login` and `register`, to the right in the main nav, using the class `navbar-right`

***HTML***

```
<nav class="navbar bg--lighter-blue">
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-md-right">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">Benefits</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">How it works</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">Contact</a></li>    
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="subpages/login.html">Login</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link txt--white text-uppercase" href="#">Register</a></li>   
            </ul>                                   
        </div>      
    </div>                  
</nav>
```

***CSS***

```
.header-container { 
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;   
 width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 docs:

> Added .float-{xs,sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none} classes for responsive floats and removed .pull-left and .pull-right since they’re redundant to .float-xs-left and .float-xs-right.

Utilities section
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

So you can use float-{xs,sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none} classes